# Toggling a class with jquery

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Hi I want to toggle the **on-off** class but only one can be selected, something similar to a radio input:

```
$('.text-selection').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('on-off');
});
```

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/MFQc9/3/). Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the class from the siblings of the current element:

```
$('.text-selection').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('on-off').siblings().removeClass('on-off');
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MFQc9/4/**

Answer (score 2):

Remove the class from the selected item, and then add the class to the one that was clicked on:

```
$('.text-selection').on('click', function () {
    $('.on-off').removeClass('on-off');
    $(this).toggleClass('on-off');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spaU9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the class `'on-off'` for the other elements with the class `'.text-selection'` when any item is clicked.

```
$('.text-selection').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('on-off');
    $('.text-selection').not(this).removeClass('on-off');
});
```

**[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MFQc9/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the ones already on before toggling them, like so:

```
$('.text-selection').on('click', function () {
    $('.text-selection').removeClass('on-off');
    $(this).toggleClass('on-off');
});
```

Comment: That will remove the class from the item that was clicked on, not the previously selected item.

Comment: It will remove the class from all of them.  After resetting, the one chosen will be toggled on.

Comment: It does exactly the same as your solution.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, but not necessary to remove from all of them. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$('.point-and-click').removeClass('on-off');` as the first statement in your function